# Generate surface equation from x, y, z data

Tags: python, math, numpy, spline, surface

What is the most effective way of generating an equation for a surface where x, y and z are known? There seems to be many ways to interpolate spline by spline from a few data points, however, I have all the data points that represent a smooth surface and would still not have a single equation representing the whole surface. Each spline is fairly simple in that it rises and falls once.

I have generated an equation from a least squares example on [Brandon Stafford's blog](http://pingswept.org/2009/06/15/least-squares-fit-of-a-surface-to-a-3d-cloud-of-points-in-python-(with-ridiculous-application)/), but the resulting equation does not represent the more complicated form.

I realize the cross terms are missing. How can I add each cross term (xy, xy^2, x^2y, x^3y, x^3y^2, y^3x, y^3x^2) into the script? Once I have cross terms do I need to add degrees for them?

```
# Set up the canonnical least squares form
Ax = np.vander(X,degree)
Ay = np.vander(Y,degree)
A = np.hstack((Ax,Ay))

# Solve for the least squares estimate of current
(coeffs, residuals, rank, sing_vals) = np.linalg.lstsq(A, Z)

# Extract coefficients and create polynomials in x and y
xcoeffs = coeffs[0:degree]
ycoeffs = coeffs[degree:2 * degree]

fx = np.poly1d(xcoeffs)
fy = np.poly1d(ycoeffs)

print fx
print fy
```